# Failed to start process automatic reporting is enabled

Tags: boot, login, lenovo, 22.04, recovery-mode

I've recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop, and all was running smoothly until this morning, when I tried to log in and got an error: `Oh no!  Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. All extensions have been disabled as a precaution.` I tried multiple again, and it didn't work. When I try to log in, the desktop will be briefly displayed before this error message pops up, prompting me to log out and try again. After pressing the `Log out` button, the following flashes across the screen: `[FAILED] Failed to start Process automatic reporting is enabled.`

Something I noticed is that when the desktop flashes, the application icons in the sidebar were slightly different then they normally are. I'm not exactly sure what this means, though.

So I used `CTRL` `ALT` `F3` to open up a command line interface. Network seems to be working, as I updated and upgraded the system, but to no avail.

I'm able to read logs, but frankly, I don't really know what they mean, or which one to even take a look at. If somebody could help me out here, that would be greatly appreciated.

Some other info: I have a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5, dual-booting Ubuntu 22.04 with Windows 11. Windows works just fine when I boot it. I am able to enter recovery mode and root shell.

**Update:** I tried to boot again, and for some reason it became stuck on these two lines of text:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[FAILED] Failed to start Light Display Manager.
```

I was unable to reproduce this on recovery mode, only on normal boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

It turns out that I had switched over from `gdm3` to `lightdm`, which prevented the desktop from appearing.

To fix, I entered recovery mode, dropped into a root shell, and ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

After that, I got a prompt that made me choose between `lightdm` and `gdm3`, and choosing `gdm3` allowed me to fix the issue.