# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS wifi connected but no working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, dns

No problem with computer before connected to a airport wifi, I did using VPN.

I don't know if its correlated but I'm desparate and I'm looking to check everything to solve it

1)
I turned off my PC and I got
**"Failed to start process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled"**

I tried to solve with this guide but still no working

[Failed to start process automatic reporting is enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422552/failed-to-start-process-automatic-reporting-is-enabled)

I got unable to locate lightdm

-I turned on and I solved using:
sudo systemctl disable apport.service

2)
I realized after that wifi was connected but not working so:

• I tried Changing the resolv.conf file and still no working

$ cd /etc
$ sudo nano resolv.conf

Changed the Content as following:

## Generated by NetworkManager

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

•sudo systemctl restard Network manager

•Following this video: https://youtu.be/Rc7lZV_xvTU

3)

I think it's something related with drivers:
[image]

4)
The stranger fact is that if i connect with my virtual box i can connect with internet

Still not working, i tried in the last week almost every video and guides here, can someone help me?
Thank you in advance

---

UPDATE
(i'm still replying from VBOX)

Thank's to @user68186 i've open the VPN and turned off "kill switch" and wifi is working again.

But is really slow, almost 2min to reload the page and google chrome is not working:
"Google chrome is not responding
You may choose to wait a bit ecc.."

the results of:

[image: SUDO APT GET UPDATE]

**SUDO APT GET UPDATE**

**SUDO APT-GET UPGRADE**

Fetched 781 MB in 1min 16s (10.3 MB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I finally update the **driver nvidia to 515**, do you suggest other one?

Comment: Which VPN did you use, an office/work provided VPN or a consumer grade one? This usually happens when the VPN is not deactivated properly. Try opening the VPN client and disable the"kill switch". If that does not work, first uninstall the VPN client and then turn the computer off and on.

Comment: @user68186 i used "Touch VPN" (an extension of google chrom) and "Windscribe" , so you think they did it? 
But is strange because i use it very often

Comment: Can you add `dkms status` something is off with package-management I think. Also `uname -r` Can you try boot up an older kernel? Can you check if network connection works there?